# STOMP Spring WebSocket message exceeds size limit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am implementing Spring WebSocket into our Spring MVC web application. However I am running into message over size limits when I am trying to send a really big message to an endpoint.

I am getting the following error:

```
message:The 'content-length' header 68718  exceeds the configured message buffer size limit 65536

14:49:11,506 ERROR [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) Failed to parse TextMessage payload=[13684590},..], byteCount=16384, last=true] in session vlsxdeol. Sending STOMP ERROR to client.: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: The 'content-length' header 68718  exceeds the configured message buffer size limit 65536
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.BufferingStompDecoder.checkBufferLimits(BufferingStompDecoder.java:148) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.BufferingStompDecoder.decode(BufferingStompDecoder.java:124) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Here is my configuration:

```
@MessageMapping("/user/sockettest" )
@SendTo("/topic/sockettestresult")
public String sockAdd(ListId[] listIds) {
..
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

return stringRet;
}
```

The xml config looks like the following:

```
<websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/user/sockettest">
<websocket:sockjs/>
</websocket:stomp-endpoint>

<websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>

<websocket:message-converters register-defaults="false">
    <bean id="mappingJackson2MessageConverter" class="org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"></property>
    </bean>
</websocket:message-converters>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

The client side code looks like this:

```
function versionFiles() {
        stompClient.send("/testbrkr/user/sockettest", {}, JSON.stringify(listIds));
    }
```

Can you let me know what would be a good work-around?

**Answer**: If you know what would be the maximum size limit

```
 <websocket:transport message-size="75536" send-buffer-size="75536"></websocket:transport>
```

I am looking on how to do partial messaging, will post it here as soon as I find out and get it working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider `<websocket:transport message-size=""/>` option for the `<websocket:message-broker>` definition:

> Configure the maximum size for an incoming sub-protocol message.
>       For example a STOMP message may be received as multiple WebSocket messages
>       or multiple HTTP POST requests when SockJS fallback options are in use.

The same can be achieved in annotation configuration using `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration)` implementation and with the `setMessageSizeLimit()` on the matter.

Comment: Thank you, that partially worked for sending the message but I am unable to receive the message on the client side...

Comment: Maybe `setSendBufferSizeLimit()` is for you?

Comment: That worked! Here is how I did it in xml <websocket:transport message-size="75536" send-buffer-size="75536">
  </websocket:transport>                                                                                  I am currently looking into partial messages..

Comment: Is there any out of the box support in spring for splitting websocket messages?

Comment: Looks like fully separate question. And yes: Spring Integration is there for you: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#splitter

Comment: Here is an actual doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#splitter

Answer (score 7):

I was getting similar javascript errorr when the default value of 65kb was set.. then i set it to some random and again got some error like the

> connection was interrupted

. So tried increasing the time limit and that worked for me. Actually when the limit exceeds, the messages are sent into packets/or frames, and while it was receiving the response from server, it timed out.

You can use tweak it as below

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class AppWebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
----
---
    @Override
        public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
            registration.setMessageSizeLimit(200000); // default : 64 * 1024
            registration.setSendTimeLimit(20 * 10000); // default : 10 * 10000
            registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(3* 512 * 1024); // default : 512 * 1024

        }
---
}
```

Comment: adding to @Ashutosh's answer, I found this spring doc page you can refer to 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketTransportRegistration.html

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>();
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(512*1024);  //FIX
        WebSocketClient wsClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(wsClient));
//      transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());

        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
        stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(512 * 1024);      //FIX
```

---

Lines commented as FIX resolved the issue for me.

---

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue and solved by configuring WebSocketTransportRegistration and ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketTransportRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/echo").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(2048 * 2048);
        registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(2048 * 2048);
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(2048 * 2048);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createServletServerContainerFactoryBean() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(2048 * 2048);
        factoryBean.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(2048 * 2048);
        factoryBean.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(2048L * 2048L);
        factoryBean.setAsyncSendTimeout(2048L * 2048L);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `<websocket:transport message-size=""/>` option for the `<websocket:message-broker>` definition:

Configure the maximum size for an incoming sub-protocol message. For example a STOMP message may be received as multiple WebSocket messages or multiple HTTP POST requests when SockJS fallback options are in use.

The same can be achieved in annotation configuration using

```
WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration)
```

implementation and with the `setMessageSizeLimit()` on the matter.

This is right but... If you are using Spring WebSocket then the stomp message is

```
StompSubProtocolHandler
```

and

```
@Override
    public void afterSessionStarted(WebSocketSession session, MessageChannel outputChannel) {
        if (session.getTextMessageSizeLimit() < MINIMUM_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SIZE) {
            session.setTextMessageSizeLimit(MINIMUM_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        }
        this.decoders.put(session.getId(), new BufferingStompDecoder(this.stompDecoder, getMessageSizeLimit()));
    }
```

so here is the spring bug message size is set as websocket:transport message-size but the WebSocketSession is not ... is 8KB and this method will double it. No as the message that we want to send.

I do not know how to fix that; You need to set WebSocketSession `TextMessageSizeLimit`. Maybe someone how know better spring boot factory knows a spring way to change the WebSocketSession `textMessageSizeLimit`.
Anyway I did with Aop `DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor`

in the `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

```
 @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
        registry.setMessageSizeLimit(50 * 1024 * 1024); //this not work todo
        registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(50 * 1024 * 1024);
        registry.setDecoratorFactories(agentWebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory());
    }

  @Bean
        public  AgentWebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory agentWebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory() {
        return new AgentWebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory();
    }
```

the `AgentWebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory` will proxy the `WebSocketHandler` to a custom `DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor`

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils;
import org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor;
import org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory;

public class AgentWebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory implements WebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory {


    @Override
    public WebSocketHandler decorate(WebSocketHandler handler) {
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.setTargetClass(AopUtils.getTargetClass(handler));
        proxyFactory.setTargetSource(new SingletonTargetSource(handler));
        proxyFactory.addAdvisor(new DefaultIntroductionAdvisor(new SubProtocolWebSocketHandlerInterceptor()));
        proxyFactory.setOptimize(true);
        proxyFactory.setExposeProxy(true);
        return (WebSocketHandler) proxyFactory.getProxy();

    }

}
```

and the custom `DefaultIntroductionAdvisor` will intercept the WebSocketHandler `afterConnectionEstablished` and set WebSocketSession `textMessageSizeLimit`

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;

public class SubProtocolWebSocketHandlerInterceptor extends DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor {

    @Override
    protected Object doProceed(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        if(mi.getMethod().getName().equals("afterConnectionEstablished") ) {
            WebSocketSession session = (WebSocketSession) mi.getArguments()[0];
            session.setTextMessageSizeLimit(50*1024*1024);
        }
        return super.doProceed(mi);
    }
}
```

This is tested and will accept message biger the 16KB
in the presented case message limit size is 50 * 1024 * 1024