# Spring Stomp Websocket - too big SEND message generates 1009 error and disconnect

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I use Spring Stomp Websocket framework. I have already configured websocket to use larger (outgoing from server?) messages as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343235/stomp-spring-web-socket-message-exceeds-size-limit, but I seem to still get error when I use "SEND" command with larger than 64 Kb payload (incoming message towards server)

```
1009 Reason: Text message size [82998] exceeds maximum size [65536]
```

Existing configuration looks like

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
    registry.setMessageSizeLimit(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE);
    registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(BUFFER_SIZE);
    super.configureWebSocketTransport(registry);
   }
}
```

I use Spring Java Stomp Client to send payloads.

It seems an additional configuration is needed either for websocket server or for the Java Spring Websocket client to allow "SEND" of larger messages.

I appreciate help figuring out what config I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add bellow config at client side

```
    final WebSocketContainer webSocketContainer = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    webSocketContainer.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(maxBinaryBufferSize);
    webSocketContainer.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(maxTextBufferSize);
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please tell me at which place this needs to be added exactly?

My configuration looks like this

`
@EnableWebSocket
public class Application implements WebSocketConfigurer {
 @Bean
 public Handler handler() {
  return new Handler();
 }
 @Override
 public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addHandler(handler(), "/helloworld");
 }
}`

And my Handler looks like this

`
public class Handler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
}
`